# How can I get a client's Name attribute with SocketServer in python?

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I'm using a class `RequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler)`to handle incoming connections to a server.

I am trying to get the name of the client which is stored as an attribute that sends data to this server, but right now I can only get it by asking for `self.client_address` which returns a tuple like `Name of client that sent request: ('127.0.0.1', 57547)`.

Is there a way to ask for an attribute of the object that initiated the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. You would have to send that name over the communication channel.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there would be another way but now at least I know I would be doing it correctly by sending the name as data.